# Help with expected frecuencies

Tags: probability, statistics

I need a list of theoretical probabilities for different laws of distribution to find expected frecuencies.

Example:

1.- Uniform distribution

- Object 1,2,3,4,5
- Frequency 34,54,39,48,45.
- $\text{probability}=p_i=1/5$
- $\text{expected frequency}=n\cdot p_i~=~220\cdot 1/5=44$

2.-Poisson:

- object 0,1,2,3,4
- frequency 63,20,8,5,4
- $\lambda=(0\cdot 63+1\cdot 20+2\cdot 8+3\cdot 5+4\cdot 4)/100$
- $\text{probability}=p_0=\exp(-\lambda\cdot 0)/0!=0.512$
- $\text{expected value}=e_0=100\cdot 0.512$

I have Uniform distribution, Poisson distribution, Exponential distribution however I can´t figure it out for Normal distribution.

Example:

- Interval 135-140,140-145,145-150,150-155,155-160,160-165
- frequency 6,18,32,61,22,5
- $\text{mean}=\bar x=150.625$
- $\text{variance}=s_x=31.425$
- $p_1=0.026,p_2=0.129$
- $e_1=4.18,e_2=18.55$

Can someone explain the normal distribution for me? I don´t know how they got the values in the worked example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are provided experimental results in the form of *sample* values and frequencies, and the type of distribution to which they *should* belong.

From the sample you *estimate* the parameters for that distribution.

Using those parameters you then calculate *theoretical* results, and compare these to the *experimental*.

For the "normal distribution" experiment, the sample results are collected by intervals. So you obtain the sample mean, you sum the product of frequency and *average of each interval*, then divide by the sum of frequencies to obtain $150.625$.

$$ \dfrac{\frac{6(135+140)}2+\frac{18(140+145)}2+\frac{32(145+150)}2+\frac{61(150+155)}2+\frac{22(155+160)}2+\frac{5(160+165)}2}{6+18+32+61+22+5}$$

Which is the usual $\bar x = \frac{\sum_i x_i f_i}{\sum_i f_i}$ where $x_i=\tfrac12(x_{i,\min}+x_{i,\max})$

The sample variance is obtained simiarly.

Comment: I figured the mean and standard deviation, however I have problems with the probability and expected frequency. I wanted to use the probability density function but I´m getting funny values.

Comment: O.I.C.! You need to use the *cummulative distribution function* to find the theoretical probability mass of each interval.  $~e_1=\mathsf P(135<X\leqslant 140)~=~F_X(140)-F_X(135)$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it!!!